# php include files from one directory to another on the same server

Tags: php, symlink

I have several instances of a CMS on the same serve  and plan to have a main hub where I can update the majority of the files which I want to include into each CMS. I was directed to symlinks by my hosting company of which I tried a test page e.g:

```
symlink('/home/site1/public_html/includes', '/home/site2/public_html/includes');
```

and tried to print out something from the site1 into site2 but I got an error

> Warning: symlink(): No such file or directory in...

I have also in desperation tried to do a basic include from site one i.e

```
include('/home/site1/public_html/includes').
```

I know I may be way off which is why I posted on here.

Comment: What is the path of the file this function is running in?

Comment: the path folder i want to include something like /home/site1/public_html/includes

Comment: But where is it being included from?

Comment: Sorry, lets say I have 2 cms's and both use the same ifles, want i want to do is remove them from one and just include them from the other....two different accounts on the server...two different domain names....hopefully that's what you want to know

Comment: There may be a security issue linking to a different domain name, depending on your host.

Comment: I have just contacted them....it was them that suggested I could do this so I'm not sure if that is the problem, but thanks

Comment: This is a security issue...they don't allow cross domain sharing of files, it will work across sub domains